# Invalid Address in PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm getting an `invalid address` error while running the PHP script below. The SMTP credentials and recipient e-mail were altered for this post. They are all valid on the actual script. I don't know why the recipient e-mail is being rejected. I'm trying to send an e-mail with SMTP authentication, and SMTP security (SSL, TLS) is not required.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
  include 'PHPMailer_5.2.2/class.phpmailer.php';

  function SendConfirmation ($sName, $sEmail)
  {
    $mail = new PHPMailer ();

    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;

    $mail->Host = "mail.exchange.telus.com";
    $mail->IsSMTP ();
    $mail->Username = "inbin@website.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";

    $mail->From = "inbin@website.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Web Site";

    $mail->AddAddress ($sEmail, $sName);

    $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test' . date ('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $mail->Body = "This is a test.";

    if ($mail->Send ())
      echo "\r\nMail sent.";
    else
      echo "\r\nMail not sent. " .  $mail->ErrorInfo;

    echo "\r\n";
  }  

  /***[ Main ] **************************************************************************/

  $sName = 'Johan Cyprich';
  $sEmail = 'jcyprich@website.com';

  $bSent = SendConfirmation ($sName, $sEmail);
```

Comment: do any emails, for example, sending to yourself work?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Are you certain you're sending it to the outbound SMTP server and not one that only accepts incoming mail for certain domains? [shockingly common mistake]

Comment: Yes. I have Joomla 2.5 installed on the same server and its sending e-mails through its own phpmailer using the SMTP authenticated server. I've tried other PHP SMTP libraries and they were able to send e-mails, but those libraries didn't meet my requirements in the way that PHPMailer does. Its probably some switch in PHPMailer that needs to be set. :)

Comment: This is the error message I'm getting:

---
Invalid address: jcyprich@website.com
You must provide at least one recipient email address.
---

I use the same SMTP settings for my Outlook e-mail and also these settings are used in various web site and applications (PHP, ASP.NET) on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have valid email addresses for `AddReplyTo` and/or `AddAddress`.

I had the same problem and it turned out to be because I was setting empty values for `AddReplyTo`.